# Using partial derivative to check PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the PDE $u_x+y u_y=0$,

Claim:The directional derivative in the direction of the vector $(1,y) $is zero.

The directional derive is given $D_uf(x,y)=f_x(x,y) a+f_y(x,y) b$, I want to check this 
So I have  $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0 $ But somehow I am not sure how to plug in $(1,y)$ to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to know the fact that for any vector $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^2$, the derivative of $u(x,y)$ in the direction $\vec{v}$ is given by $$
D_{\vec{v}}u=\nabla u\cdot \vec{v}.
$$
Hence, applying the latter formula with the vector $\vec{v}:=(1,y)$ we obtain $$
D_{(1,y)}u=\nabla u\cdot (1,y)^t=\partial_xu+y\partial_yu=0,
$$
where in the last equality we have used the fact that $u$ solves the PDE.